# Intercept http request for the files on file server

Tags: asp.net, wcf, httphandler, httpmodule

> http://myfileserver/images/car/chevrolet.gif

I have this file server holding the files such as images, doc files etc. Now i want to intercept the http request and based on the file extension i want perform some action such as redirection to some other webpage.

What is the best and the easier way to accomplish this thing?  I am using asp.net framework for my applications.

Pls suggest the approach.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to intercept the request for specific file types, then go with an Http Handler. Here is the MSDN link explaining their usage - [Http Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c67a8bd%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In the WCF world if you're looking to handle an HTTP request with a different option based on the requested filetype, you may want to look into adding an `IDispatchOperationSelector`, which allows the service to route the code through a different operation. The default HTTP implementation is the `WebHTTPDispatchOperationSelector`, which is explained pretty well [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.webhttpdispatchoperationselector.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/10/wcf-extensibility-operation-selectors.aspx).

If you want to remain in the Asp.Net world, I'd recomend going with custom message handlers. Here's an [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers) by Mike Wasson explaining how these work & where they fall in the Asp stack.

Comment: i haven't decided yet to use WCF. If something else is easy and simple, i heard that MS Web API is quick for such things.. But i do not know how to use it..

Comment: just added an edit containing some information about the MS Web API version of OperationSelectors